# ActivatedRoute.queryParams is undefined

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to capture a querystring parameter using Angular 2.0 and am having a hard time. I have a url like so

http://localhost:5000/?id_token=eyJ0eXAiO....

And I want to be able to capture the value of id_token before routing takes hold and I lose the parameter. I found this GitHub Issue Thread

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9451

But this uses a deprecated method that no longer works. I have tried the following methods

```
    var foo = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);
        let id = params['id_token'];
        console.log(id);
    });


   console.log(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.queryParams["id_token"]);

   var bar = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
        (param: any) => console.log(param['id_token']));
```

I have tried these methods in the constructor as well as ngOnInit() of my component, but the console always shows undefined. Am I doing this in the wrong place. I am not able to change the QS at all because it is being created by Azure AD.

Answer (score 7):

Try injecting ActivatedRoute and get the queryParam with `route.snapshot.queryParams['name']` like this:

```ts
class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        let value = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['name'];
    }
}
```

Setting the queryParams via router.navigate works like this:

```ts
class SomeComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }
    goSomewhere(): void {
        this.router.navigate(['somewhere'], { queryParams: { name: 'value' } });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I have tried everything that the OP put as well as what you stated. I don't know if the OP is having the same issue as me, but I am getting to my route as a login callback, not navigating from somewhere else in the application.

My url is `http://myhost/?code=1234#/auth/callback` and the router quickly reroutes to `http://myhost/#/auth/callback` before the component is instantiated.

Comment: @JonTinsman Did you solve this? I am facing the exact problem

Comment: @masterfan I had to remove the hash navigation. The reason for my issue is when the auth server built the reroute, it didn't tack on the `code` onto the end, but used a builder that put the hash after the query parameters. The original reason the main developer used hash navigation seemed to be no longer needed and it worked once we did `http://myhost/auth/callback?code=1234` I was then able to access the query parameter through the `activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['code']`