# Angular: snapshot.params id comes undefined

Tags: angular, parameters

Im working with this fake api 'jsonplaceholder' getting and sending data with one model: Users. My goal is to display a list of Users and on each click I navigate to other component where I can see it's Id. But so far I can only display the list; the id comes undefined and I can't do nothing more. I tried to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362619/activatedroute-queryparams-is-undefined) but it didnt work. Can someone help?

The Service:

```
getUsers(): Observable<Users> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }) 
    };
    return this.http.get<Users>(this.urlUsers, httpOptions).pipe(
      retry(3),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Home.TS

```
  users: Users;
  id: string;
  constructor(private router: Router,
    private dataService: DataService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.id =  this.route.snapshot.params['id'];  
    console.log(this.id); -----> undefined
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
 }

  getUsers() {
    this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data;
      console.log(this.users);

    });
  }

getById(){
  this.dataService.getById(this.id).subscribe(data => {
    this.users=data['id'];
    this.router.navigate(['/second, users.id'])
  })
}
```

HOME HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <ul *ngFor="let user of users">
    <li (click) = "getById();">{{user.name}}</li> ---->backend returns 404
  </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT:My Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'second',
    component: SecondComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
];
```

And paramsMap don't work either...

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add `second/:id` to your routes. That is the reason backend could not find the route.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'second',
    component: SecondComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'second/:id',
    component: SecondComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
];
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to get `paramMap` check [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route)

`this.route.paramMap['id'];`